# Convert dicom to jpg

Tags: java

```
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.jpeg2000.J2KRenderedImageCodecLib.<init>(J2KRenderedImageCodecLib.java:225)
    at com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.jpeg2000.J2KImageReaderCodecLib.read(J2KImageReaderCodecLib.java:364)
    at org.dcm4che3.imageio.plugins.dcm.DicomImageReader.read(DicomImageReader.java:284)
    at com.panemr.dicom.util.DicomToImageConverter.readImage(DicomToImageConverter.java:345)
    at com.panemr.dicom.util.DicomToImageConverter.convert(DicomToImageConverter.java:322)
    at com.panemr.dicom.util.DicomToImageConverter.mconvert(DicomToImageConverter.java:307)
    at com.panemr.dicom.helper.ImageConverterHelper.convertDicomToJPEGFormat(ImageConverterHelper.java:44)
    at com.panemr.dicom.action.DicomConnectionAction.initiateImageConverter(DicomConnectionAction.java:93)
    at com.panemr.dicom.action.DicomConnectionAction.fetchDicomFromDCM(DicomConnectionAction.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:453)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:292)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:255)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
```

I checked com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.jpeg2000.J2KRenderedImageCodecLib class, and found that the value of xStep and yStep variables is not set:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size.csize; i++) {
    decoder.decodeCompParams(compParam, i);
    if(i == 0) {
        xStep = compParam.xstep;
        yStep = compParam.ystep;
    } else if(compParam.xstep != xStep || compParam.ystep != yStep) {
        // All components must have same subsampling along each axis.
        throw new IIOException
        ("All components must have the same subsampling factors!");
    }
}
```

because this loop is not running. What do I have to do to run it?

Comment: if the xStep and yStep is not set, then it means that something is wrong with decodeCompParams() method

Comment: Hi Ondkloss, thanx for rply! yes you are right. actually decodeCompParams() method contains a native method. And i dont have any sort of code. Can you please suggest me the link to source code of same file

Comment: size.csize is set to 0, and its value does not change. I dont know why that is why this loop is not running.How to find the code of native methods of com.sun.medialib.codec.jp2k package classes. I dint get source code of it from any where on net